Windows 8.1 installation fails returning a blue screen with internal_power_error
Today I was installing windows 8.1 and everything seemed to go smoothly until the second stage of the installation. My pc restarted and a bsod quickly flashed an error that I could not read at first, but took a slow motion shot of it and it read: internal_power_error. I disabled vmd for windows to detect my drives and disabled secure boot and tpm. Does this error have anything to do with that?
Thanks in advance.Error

I’ve seen others install win 8.1 on tigerlake cpus.

I managed to install windows 8.1 on the Ideapad 3 by first disabling the vmd controller in my BIOS, disabling secure boot, going back into the installation media, pressing shift and f10 on my pc to open cmd, going to notepad, and deleting intelpep.sys which was located in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers.
Then, I booted back into windows 8.1, and continued the rest of the install.
NOTE: Delete intelpep.sys by using these instructions every time the system updates.
